# How do I use CSS to position text or an image firmly?

Tags: html, css

When I have a webpage in HTML change window sizes, the text will remain at 50% and not just stay the same formatting, or will wrap around an image because it's not positioned correctly. How do I keep it in it's own little invisible box to stay that format even when the window size changes?

text that I want centered but not to change position when the window size changes

Comment: Can you please provide an example? E.g. the html and css code you're using?

Comment: If you add a width and a height attribute to the image, the image will stay that size regardless of the window size. For example, width: 800px; height: 600px;

Answer (score 1):

I hope I didn't misunderstand your question but if you want to keep that text in one place maybe try with "position:" property (for example: "position: absolute" etc.").